# Android deeplink Intent Filter with plain/text

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, intentfilter

I am trying to configure a deep link `intent-filter` to open an Android app from a QR Code scanned by the Camera.

The data value of the QR Code is "tagname:datavalue", presumably a "text/plain" mime type, but I don't know this for sure.

In my `AndroidManifest.xml` I have the following intent within an activity:

```
    <activity
        android:name="a.b.activity.DeepLinkActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

It wants me include a scheme of which there is none; it's just plain text data.

When the QR Code is scanned by the Camera, I can launch Chrome, but I want to add the option of opening my app. Is this possible?

When I add a mimetype without a scheme, Android Studio wants to add a scheme value `android:scheme="<some-scheme>" tools:ignore="AppLinkUrlError"` to the `intent-filter`.

```
        <intent-filter android:scheme="<some-scheme>"
            tools:ignore="AppLinkUrlError">
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
```

But there is no scheme.

Bonus question: Can I filter on specific values of `tagname`, for example launch the app if `tagname` is "apple", but not "orange"?

Answer (score 1):

Add the scheme as the content and it won't show the error again.

```
  <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" android:scheme="content"/>
  </intent-filter>
```